# WifiManager getConnectionInfo() got deprecated in Android API level 31

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-11, wifimanager

We uses Wifimanger getConnectionInfo() method to get SSID and BBSID of connected wifi.
But starting with Andorid API level 31 , Android has deprecated the getConnectionInfo() method.

The solution that they have provided to use getTransportInfo() required minimum Android level 29 which we cannot target , given our 20 percent user still on Android API level below 29.

Can someone help with the alternative method to get connected wifi.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo()

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NetworkCallback()` instead.
You need to pass `FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO` to `NetworkCallback()`, otherwise you will get "unknow ssid" only.
Also you need the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions to make it work.

```
            val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .build()
            val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(
                FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO) {
                override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
                    network: Network,
                    networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
                ) {
                    super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
                    val wifiInfo = networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo
                    val ssid = wifiInfo.ssid
                }
            }
            connManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback)
```

Refer to: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConnectionInfo().